# WPF Datagrid dosnt show the queryresult, even its bound

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

i have a problem.
I have a datagrid wich is bound to "Patient_view":

```
 private ObservableCollection<pViewModel> patient_view;

            public ObservableCollection<pViewModel> Patient_view
            {
                get
                {
                    return patient_view;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (Patient_view != value)
                    {
                        patient_view = value;
                        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient_view");
                    }
                }
            }
```

If i start my program, the datagrid shows the queryresult from this query:

```
 public static IList<Patient_Anschrift_List> Patients { get; private set; }

        static PatientList()
        {
            using (dbentities context = new dbentities())
            {
                Patients = new List<Patient_Anschrift_List>();
                Patients = (from p in ..
                            select new Patient_Anschrift_List()
                            {..}

        }
```

Okay, thats fine. But now i want to use some other querys (they are already written. my program basically already works, but have to put it into the mvvm pattern, wich is hard for me because im not realy experienced in programming).

My problem is, that the datagrid dosnt show the other queryresults.
on startup it get filled with:

```
 public pViewModelList()
        {
            patient_view = new ObservableCollection<pViewModel>(PatientList.Patients.Select(p => new pViewModel(p)));

            //patients.CollectionChanged += Patients_AddCollection;
        }
```

but if i try to change the collection on a buttonpress, it just dont do anything. it keep showing the old results.
thats what im doing on buttonpress:

```
 private void ExecuteAddPatientCommand()
        {
            // Patients.Add(new pViewModel(new Patient()));
            Abfragen abfragen = new Abfragen();
            Eingaben_prüfen p = new Eingaben_prüfen();

            List<Patient_Anschrift_List> ausgabe = new List<Patient_Anschrift_List>();

            ausgabe = abfragen.select_Patients(p.Nachname(eingabe1), p.Vorname(eingabe1), p.Versichertenstatus(eingabe1)...);
         //   patient_view.Clear();
            patient_view = new ObservableCollection<pViewModel>(ausgabe.Select(s => new pViewModel(s)));
```

if i do this:

```
patient_view.Add(new pViewModel(new dModel.Patient_Anschrift_List{Nachname ="test", Vorname = "test"}));
```

instead of the select, it adds a new row and instantly show it at the grid.

Can you please tell me what im doing wrong?
And do you need some more details?
thank you
(hope you understand my english)

Comment: have you set the Binding Model Twoway ?

Comment: Yes, thats how i bound this:
 <DataGrid x:Name="dgrid" Margin="30,20,374,0" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
         IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Patient_view, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Patient_selected_item, Mode=TwoWay}"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Height="652" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Patient_view,Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: Jup, had it. Just copyed the wrong thing :D (tock it out for testing if it make a difference)

Comment: then explicity called notifyproperty changed like NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient_view"); after changing the Patient_view

Comment: hue hue hue hue
thx!
that worked, didnt expect that its that simple :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the private property `patient_view`, which does not raise the PropertyChange notification.

Change your code to set the public property `Patient_view`, which raises a PropertyChange notification in the `set` method, and is the version bound to the View.

```
Patient_view = new ObservableCollection<pViewModel>(ausgabe.Select(s => new pViewModel(s)));
```

The reason it works using the private property to `.Add` is because you're using an `ObservableCollection`, which automatically notifies the UI to update whenever an item is added or removed.

But in the case of the code sample above, you are changing the value entirely instead of only adding or removing an item to the existing collection, so a change notification is needed to tell the UI that it needs to update.

Comment: if we are explicity called notifyproperty changed then it's work or we have to set the public property like Patient_view

Comment: @DhavalPatel Yes, explicitly calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient_view")` after updating the private property does work as well, although I try to avoid that for a number of reasons. I don't like the extra line of code, don't like the chance that me or another developer will forget that extra line of code, and don't like the fact it bypasses any other logic placed in the  `set` method of the property (a common example is I will frequently attach/detach `CollectionChanged` events in the `set` method of an `ObservableCollection`) :)

Comment: And how i set the change notification? 
Sry, but as i telled, im realy new to this :(

Comment: @user3793935 `NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient_view")` is your change notification, and its already being called in the `set { ... }` of your `Patient_view` property. So you merely have to change "`patient_view = new ...`" to "`Patient_view = new ...`" (note the capital `P` which means this will set the public property and use the `set { ... }` method of it, instead of the small `p` which sets the private field, with no change notification)

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Patient_view, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Mode TwoWay is crap, your datagrid will never set the itemssource back to your viewmodel, so you can simply remove it. its OneWay by default.

```
 patient_view = new ObservableCollection<pViewModel>(PatientList.Patients.Select(p => new pViewModel(p)));
```

if you set the Patient_View this way, wpf has no chance to get notified. there are 3 ways to fix this.

1. initialize a ObservableCollection just once and use Clear(), Add(), Remove() methods to alter it. this is what i prefer
2. set the new ObservableCollection to your property not to your field, so NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient_view") is called
3. call NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient_view") after you set the new ObservableCollection to your field

Answer (score 0):

You forgot implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel. 
See a [really cool example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-MVVM-Examples-fb8c409f) by Microsoft.

Another [example](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html).

INotifyPropertyChanged provides Two-way DataBinding so your changes of View will be reflected in Model layer.

Comment: @user3793935, if it helps for your task, please mark it as an answer.